# How to use string input to execute function inside class?

Tags: python, oop

I'm stucking with the process of user input a string to execute a function without using dictionary of functions. Specifically, I defined a class

```
class Myclass():
    def __init__(self, df):
        ...
        return

    def function_1(self, **kwargs):
        return result
    
    def function_2(self, **kwargs):
        return result
    ...
```

User from the frontend give an input in string, like `"function_1"`. I wonder how can I execute the method of class right away using this string as below

```
# From frontend
receive = Input() # receive will be the string right now when user choose "function_1"
print(receive)
>>> "function_1"

# From backend
result = Myclass(df).function_1()
```

### Solution that I have tried

I have tried to use

```
def MyFunction(dataframe, userFunctionChoose:str, **kwargs):
    tasks = {}
    def task(task_fn):
       tasks[task_fn.__name__] = task_fn

    @task
    def function_1(dataframe):
       return result
   
    @task
    def function_2(dataframe):
       return result
    return tasks[userFunctionChoose]()

result = MyFunction(dataframe, "function_1")
```

Although it's worked properly, however,  I still need to create a class for other use-cases, and it contains more than 50 methods inside.

With the input string, how can I make the `Myclass` run the required method as nested function?

Comment: It seems you are looking for the [getattr()](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/functions.html#getattr) function

Comment: @quamrana ```getattr()``` still not gives me the final result, it  is just the detail address of the function on memory ``<bound method MyClass.method of <some object at 0x7f3b072474f0>>. Here I need it returns the numpy array as I designed

Comment: Yes, `getattr()` can be used to return a bound method. You should call that method.

Comment: I've added another duplicate which may be closer to what you are looking for,